# rpm package deleted automatically

Tags: 18.04, rpm, slack

I want to install the Slack app on my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS system. I downloaded it from here https://slack.com/intl/en-tn/downloads/linux and it gave me an rpm package file (slack-4.14.0-0.1.fc21.x86_64.rpm). I installed it using this command

```
sudo alien -i slack-4.14.0-0.1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

It worked fine but then two days later it just disappeared, it was removed, so I reinstalled it and the same thing happened again.
So I was wondering if anyone knows why is this happening and how to fix it so that the app is permanently installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Give the official Snap a go and you should be in good shape.
`sudo snap install --classic slack`

Another option would be to download the `.deb` file from the same page *(much less noticable but there)* and install it using `sudo apt install /path/to/your/file.deb`

Comment: Extra:  The `.rpm` package file you downloaded is meant for distros that use the `RPM` package format, like Fedora or RHEL.
Ubuntu, as well as *(at least most)* other Debian based distros use the `DEB` package format *(`.deb`)*. The `alien` command line tool *(if I remember correctly anyways)* allows you to install apps packaged as `RPM`s on distros that use `DEB` packages, which is why it initially worked, however it has it's issues *(as you have experienced)*

Comment: Side Note:  I went to the Slack download page, and they do have the `RPM` package promoted front and center with it's nice big download button, with the other install methods *(`Snap Store` and `.deb`)* as less noticable links, so I can see how these events have transpired

Comment: Thanks, now I used snap to install slack hope I want have the same problem in a couple of days.